# Creating a date column using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like below.

| Id | d_of_arr | d_of_sty |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-12-03 | 2021-12-04 |
| 1 | 2021-12-03 | 2021-12-05 |
| 1 | 2021-12-03 | 2021-12-06 |
| 2 | 2021-12-09 | 2021-12-10 |
| 2 | 2021-12-09 | 2021-12-11 |

I want to add a column which shows the arrival date and all the dates of staying like below,

| Id | dates |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-12-03 |
| 1 | 2021-12-04 |
| 1 | 2021-12-05 |
| 1 | 2021-12-06 |
| 2 | 2021-12-09 |
| 2 | 2021-12-10 |
| 2 | 2021-12-11 |

How to do this using python/pandas?

Comment: Soem problem with solution?

Comment: No, some problem in my browser, because after accepting the answer and upvoting it didn't show me the updated status. So did again and it was like undoing. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If performance or large DataFrame use [`Index.repeat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.repeat.html) by difference by days for duplicate rows, add timedeltas by counter [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) and [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html) and last sorting with remove duplicates:

```
df['d_of_arr'] = pd.to_datetime(df['d_of_arr'])
df['d_of_sty'] = pd.to_datetime(df['d_of_sty'])

df = df.loc[df.index.repeat(df['d_of_sty'].sub(df['d_of_arr']).dt.days.add(1))]
df['dates'] = df['d_of_arr'].add(pd.to_timedelta(df.groupby(level=0).cumcount(), unit='d'))

df1 = df[['Id','dates']].sort_values(['Id','dates']).drop_duplicates(ignore_index=True)
```

Or if small DataFrame or performance not important use list comprehension with [`DataFrame.explode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) for new rows:

```
df['dates'] = [pd.date_range(s, e) for s, e in zip(df['d_of_arr'], df['d_of_sty'])]


df1 = (df.explode('dates')[['Id','dates']]
         .sort_values(['Id','dates'])
         .drop_duplicates(ignore_index=True))
print (df1)
   Id      dates
0   1 2021-12-03
1   1 2021-12-04
2   1 2021-12-05
3   1 2021-12-06
4   2 2021-12-09
5   2 2021-12-10
6   2 2021-12-11
```